# Erratic behavior of arithmetic operators

Tags: javascript, arithmetic-expressions

I have this JavaScript program that is suppose to do very simple math from the user input (2 numbers, one of four operators - +,-,/,*). Problem is that the results are erratic (maybe not the best word because there is a pattern, but ahead with terminology) and I have no idea why.

By erratic I mean that, for example, if you start by summing 5+5 it will yield 10, as expected, but if you do a second try with 5+6 you will get 12, if you try 5+7 the result will be 14 and so on...

Any ideas on why this happens? Here is the code:

```
<HEAD>

<h2>A simple JavaScript powered calculator</h2>

<INPUT value="Enter a number" id="input1"></INPUT>
<SELECT id = "operator">
  <option id="choose" >choose </option>
  <option id="sum" value="+">sum</option>
  <option id="subtraction" value="-">subtraction</option>
  <option id="division" value="/">division</option>
  <option id="multiplication" value="*">multiplication</option>  
</SELECT>
<INPUT  value="Enter a number" id="input2"></INPUT>
<INPUT value= "calculate" type="button" onclick=result()></INPUT>
<INPUT id="outputfield" type="text"></INPUT>

</HEAD>

<BODY>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    function sum(number, number) {return number + number};
    function subtraction(number, number) {return number - number};
    function division(number, number) {return number / number};
    function multiplication(number, number) {return number * number};

    function result(){if (document.getElementById("operator").value === document.getElementById("sum").value) {console.log("its a +!"), document.getElementById("outputfield").value = 
                          sum(parseInt(document.getElementById("input1").value), parseInt(document.getElementById("input2").value));}

                     else if (document.getElementById("operator").value === document.getElementById("subtraction").value) {console.log("its a -!"), document.getElementById("outputfield").value = 
                          subtraction(parseInt(document.getElementById("input1").value), parseInt(document.getElementById("input2").value));}

                     else if (document.getElementById("operator").value === document.getElementById("division").value) {console.log("its a /!"), document.getElementById("outputfield").value = 
                          division(parseInt(document.getElementById("input1").value), parseInt(document.getElementById("input2").value));}

                     else if (document.getElementById("operator").value ===  document.getElementById("multiplication").value) {console.log("its a *!"), document.getElementById("outputfield").value = 
                          multiplication(parseInt(document.getElementById("input1").value), parseInt(document.getElementById("input2").value));}

                     else if (document.getElementById("operator").value === document.getElementById("choose").value) {console.log("please choose an operator");} 

                     } 

</SCRIPT>

<p> </>
<p> April 2016 </p>
</BODY>
```

Thanks in advance for any hints

Comment: Yeah. What do you think the functions will return? It does not make any sense. If `a` is 5 and `a` is 2, then what is `a + a`? `10`? `4`?

Comment: This is honestly the funniest thing I've seen all day.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen, time to go to bed here :) thanks for bothering to point the obvious though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your functions, for example:

```
function sum(number, number) {return number + number};
```

Use the same name in both parameters i.e. `number`, when you try to add 5 and 6, the name `number` is assigned the value `6` and since `6 + 6 = 12` the result is correct.

Try this instead:

```
function sum(number1, number2) {return number1 + number2};
```

Comment: And another thanks for sparing me the sarcasm ;) apparently some people here assume that everyone is an experienced programmer!